# How do I convert this Java For Each loop into a regular For loop?

Tags: java, foreach

I'm trying to convert this for each into a for loop. how do I do that?

here's the code im using

```
for (char character: word.toCharArray()) {
                    character = Character.toUpperCase(character);
                    
                    if (character >= 'A' && character <= 'Z') {
                        count[character - 'A']++;
                    }
                    
                }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's it:

```
char[] source = word.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i ++) {
     char character = Character.toUpperCase(source[i]);
     if (character >= 'A' && character <= 'Z') {
         count[character - 'A']++;
     }
}
```